# System R and RStudio using different libraries

Tags: r, rstudio

On MacOS running R-devel, I had previously symlinked Apple's Accelerate BLAS and LAPACK libraries to my R installation. I returned to R's default by reverting the symlinks, however, in RStudio (and only in RStudio), `sessionInfo()` shows Apple's BLAS library is still used. Re-installing R and RStudio managed to return LAPACK to R's defaults, but not BLAS (see below).

I've tried deleting all of my R installations (deleting `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/`), RStudio, and `~/.rstudio-desktop/` (didn't find any `.RProfile` file); then restarting; then re-installing the latest nightly build from mac.r-project.org; and finally re-installing RStudio Desktop (RStudio-1.2.5033), and nothing changes.

Terminal R session:

```
> sessionInfo()
R Under development (unstable) (2020-01-10 r77651)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.0

> .Library
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library"

> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library"
```

Rstudio R session:

```
> sessionInfo()
R Under development (unstable) (2020-01-10 r77651)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.0 tools_4.0.0   

> .Library
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library"

> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library"
```

Besides BLAS, the only other difference in `sessionInfo()` is the presence of `tools` namespace in the RStudio session.

`/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library` symlinks to `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib`:

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  3696484 Jan 10 22:36 libR.dylib
drwxrwxr-x  3 root  admin       96 Jan 10 22:36 libR.dylib.dSYM
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin   189496 Jan 10 22:36 libRblas.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin       16 Jan 12 17:32 libRblas.dylib -> libRblas.0.dylib
drwxrwxr-x  3 root  admin       96 Jan 10 22:36 libRblas.dylib.dSYM
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  2182960 Jan 10 22:36 libRlapack.dylib
drwxrwxr-x  3 root  admin       96 Jan 10 22:36 libRlapack.dylib.dSYM
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin   752876 Jan 10 22:36 libc++.1.dylib
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin   240944 Jan 10 22:36 libc++abi.1.dylib
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin   277696 Jan 10 22:36 libgcc_s.1.dylib
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  1617368 Jan 10 22:36 libgfortran.3.dylib
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin   626712 Jan 10 22:36 libomp.dylib
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin   284208 Jan 10 22:36 libquadmath.0.dylib
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin   996788 Jan 10 22:36 libreadline.5.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin       21 Jan 12 17:32 libreadline.dylib -> libreadline.5.2.dylib
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin    66848 Jan 10 22:36 libunwind.1.dylib
```

How is RStudio launching an R session that's still using the Accelerate BLAS library, and how can I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem today.  In my case, as best I could tell, `sessionInfo()` in RStudio is erroneously reporting that it was using vecLib when in reality it is not. I used the ability to multi-thread a large matrix-multiplication as my indicator of whether vecLib was actually used or not. I can see if multiple threads were used based on cpu usage in `top` and speed of computation. When I changed the symbolic link to point to the vecLib dylib, I got multithreaded behavior. When the symbolic link points at the original libRblas.0.dylib, I don't get multithreaded behavior. The output of sessionInfo is unchanged, even though the behavior is clearly different. So this looks like a bug in sessionInfo and its interaction with the RStudio environment somehow???

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib
ln -sf  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib

# restart R in RStudio and test a large muatrix multiplication--multithreaded and fast
# sessionInfo() reports /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib


ln -sf libRblas.0.dylib libRblas.dylib
#restart R  in RStudio and test same matrix multiplication--slow and single threaded
# sessionInfo still reports /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/Current/libBLAS.dylib
```

Comment: Maybe RStudio are working on some sort of automatic R BLAS/LAPACK optimisation thing that isn’t quite sorted yet. Might be worth raising it as an issue on their GitHub repo.